# How to convert this cURL to wp_remote_*?

Tags: curl, wp-remote-get, wp-remote-post

My function below includes a cURL call which throws a text string at a Google Cloud text analysis API, returning a response object, which we then parse to get a specific piece.

It has been recommended to me that I switch the cURL PHP statement to use WordPress' `wp_remote_get`.

I have read the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) for that but, to be honest, I don't understand how my cURL header fields should map to `wp_remote_get` arguments. Or even if it should be `wp_remote_post` rather than `wp_remote_get`.

How can I try and understand what to do here?

```
    function get_entity_type(
        $text_to_analyse,           // passed string to be handed to GCloud NLP
        $entity = 'type'            // part of each "entities" result to return
    ) {

        // Google Cloud API key
        $options = get_option( 'cxt_settings' );
        $google_nlp_api = $options['cxt_gcloud'];




        // Supply data payload in JSON format
        $data = '{
          "document":{
            "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
            "content":"'.$text_to_analyse.'"
          },
          "encodingType":"UTF8"
        }';
        $payload = $data;

        // Call the API endpoint, with API key
        $url = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key='.$google_nlp_api;

        // Prepare to get results using cURL
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        // Set HTTP Header for POST request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
        );

        // Submit the POST request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Store result in array
        $arr = json_decode($result, true);

        // Close cURL session handle
        curl_close($ch);




        // Pluck out the first value from the response object
        $ent_val = $arr['entities'][0][$entity];

        return $ent_val;
        // List of possible entities: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Entity#Type
        // UNKNOWN
        // PERSON
        // LOCATION
        // ORGANIZATION
        // EVENT
        // WORK_OF_ART
        // CONSUMER_GOOD
        // OTHER

    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this resource? It talks about how you can send the headers. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/#posting-data-to-an-api

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ########################################################################## *
 *
 *   DETERMINE ENTITY, via native wp_remote_post() call
 *
/* ########################################################################## */

function get_entity_type_via_wp(
    $text_to_analyse,           // passed string to be handed to GClouD NLP
    $entity = 'type'            // part of each "entities" result to return
) {

    // Google Cloud API key
    $options = get_option( 'cxt_settings' );
    $google_nlp_api = $options['cxt_gcloud'];



    // Call the API endpoint, with API key
    $url = 'https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key='.$google_nlp_api;

    // Request payload
    $payload = '{
      "document":{
        "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
        "content":"'.$text_to_analyse.'"
      },
      "encodingType":"UTF8"
    }';


    // Call Goolge NLP API via wp_remote_post();
    // cf. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/349271/how-to-convert-this-curl-to-wp-remote?noredirect=1#comment510738_349271
    //
    $result_full = wp_remote_post(
        $url,
        array(
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 45,
            'redirection' => 5,
            'httpversion' => '1.0',
            'blocking'    => true,
            'headers'     => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ),
            'body'      =>  $payload,                       // Payload, text to analyse
            'data_format' => 'body'
        )
    );


    // Just the "body" bit
    $result_entities = $result_full['body'];

    // Store result in array
    $arr = json_decode($result_entities, true);

    // Pluck out the first value from the response object
    $ent_val = $arr['entities'][0][$entity];

    return $ent_val;


    // return $ent_val;
    // List of possible entities: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Entity#Type
    // UNKNOWN
    // PERSON
    // LOCATION
    // ORGANIZATION
    // EVENT
    // WORK_OF_ART
    // CONSUMER_GOOD
    // OTHER

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this?

WordPress created by php and curl works fine in WordPress.
Curl is very powerful and has more options